# Add row to Pandas DataFrame only if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, pandas

I'm progressively appending rows to a DataFrame with data that comes from webscraping. Although, sometimes the data that I'm scraping already exists in the DataFrame, so I don't want to append it again. What's the most efficient way to check if the DataFrame already has the data? Dropping duplicates at the end is not an option, as I want to extract a specific number of records, and dropping the duplicates at the end would make the final DataFrame have less records than that specified number.

```
res = pd.DataFrame([], columns=GD_SCHEMA)

reviews = self.browser.find_elements_by_class_name('empReview')
idx = 0
for review in reviews:
    data = extract_review(review) # This is a dict with the same keys as ´res´
    
    # Most efficient way to check if ´data´ already exists in ´res´ before appending?
    res.loc[idx] = data
    idx += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using an intermediate dict. IF you choose the key to the dict *wisely*, so that the hashes of duplicates are equal, you will get a dictionary without duplicates, which you can then load into the dataframe once it has the length you require.

Comment: Is this really the best answer one can get ? At the time I am writing this comment, best option seems to either be: don't use pandas dataframe but a simple hashmap, or someone proposing to perform a linear complexity search on the table.

Answer (score 4):

Although I agree with @AndreasT that creating a dictionary before assembling a DataFrame is more efficient, I am still surprised the original question does not have an answer. It seems like what you are looking for can be simply calculated through index intersection or difference:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(100), columns=[1,2])
new_data = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(90, 110), columns = [1,2])
already_present_index = res.index.intersection(new_data.index)
missing_index = new_data.index.difference(res.index)
```

With `missing_index` you can then decide to append only those elements from `new_data` and update the original frame:

```
res.append(new_data.loc[missing_index, :])
```

If you only have one new row, you can check directly if it is already in the index by typing `new_data.index[0] in res.index`.

If your DataFrame is not too long though and you don't care about overwriting, your `.loc` assignment solution should also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two old and new dataframes that you want to combine (for example `dfOld` and `dfNew`). Each dataframe contains a unique `PrivateId` value that you do not want duplicated when the dataframes are combined. One option is to iterate through the rows of `dfNew` and check for a `PrivateId` value that does not exist in `dfOld`, then add that new row to `dfOld` only when you reach a new `PrivateId` value. See example below:

```
dfOld = pd.DataFrame({
    "PrivateId": {
        "0": "PVI0001",
        "1": "PVI0002",
        "2": "PVI0004",
        "3": "PVI0007"
    },
    "PublicId": {
        "0": "a2bb0a51",
        "1": "a2bb0a76",
        "2": "a2bb0a8a",
        "3": "a2bb0a99"
    }
})

dfNew = pd.DataFrame({
    "PrivateId": {
        "0": "PVI0011",
        "1": "PVI0003",
        "2": "PVI0007",
        "3": "PVI0306",
        "4": "PVI0001",
    },
    "PublicId": {
        "0": "b2bb0a52",
        "1": "b2bb0a44",
        "2": "b2bb0a99",
        "3": "b2bb0a33",
        "4": "bc2bb0a51",
    }
})

for i, row in dfNew.iterrows():
    if row['PrivateId'] not in dfOld['PrivateId'].values:
        print(row['PrivateId'] + ' can be added to dfOld')
        dfOld = pd.concat([dfOld, row.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True)

print(dfOld)
```

which should print out

```
PVI0011 can be added to dfOld
PVI0003 can be added to dfOld
PVI0306 can be added to dfOld
  PrivateId  PublicId
0   PVI0001  a2bb0a51
1   PVI0002  a2bb0a76
2   PVI0004  a2bb0a8a
3   PVI0007  a2bb0a99
4   PVI0011  b2bb0a52
5   PVI0003  b2bb0a44
6   PVI0306  b2bb0a33
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can compare it with the database, convert to a series then use .any() function to check if it's in the database already. It's just that it has to be completely similar. Depending on your goals, there is a tradeoff between completeness and existence of duplicates. Otherwise, you could check similarity ratios and select the appropriate cutoff.

```
    # Most efficient way to check if ´data´ already exists in ´res´ before appending?
     if pd.Series([reviews==res]).any().any().bool():
          pass
     else:
          res.loc[idx] = data
          idx += 1
```